# What does 'corporeal form' mean?

Tags: meaning, terminology

> These series, however, are only one particularly obvious example; throughout practically the whole of chemistry, even in the various nitrogen oxides and oxygen acids of phosphorus or sulfur, one can see how "quantity changes into quality", and **this** allegedly confused, hazy Hegelian notion appears in **so** to speak **corporeal form** in things and process.

- What does 'corporeal form'  mean?
- What do these pronouns substitute?
- Does "quantity changes into quality" only apply to physic objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Corporeal form**, when used literally, means the physical existence of something.  There's the idea of "you" as a self-aware entity or a soul that defines how you will behave and react, which nobody can see or touch directly; and then there's your corporeal form, which is to say your actual physical body.  Similarly, there's the mathematical concept of a square, and then there's an actual square drawn on the sidewalk in chalk.  The concept of a square has no corporeal form; the drawing takes the concept and gives it a corporeal representation.

The **this** that you highlighted is referencing the phrase "quantity changes into quality", and the author then further defines that phrase as being an "allegedly confused, hazy Hegelian notion".

The author is basically saying that you can point to something and say "at the start of this process, we have quantity.  Then things happen, and at the end of the process, we have quality.  Thus the process embodies the concept of quality changing into quantity."

Comment: +1 - The motto of my university alma mater is 'Spiritus, Mens, Corpus', literally: 'Spirit, Mind, Body'.  Here it is easy to see a distinction between the ethereal mind and spirit, and the physical (corporeal) body (corpus).  As @Hellion mentioned, a square exists in a person's mind (mens); it doesn't have a *corporeal* form until we construct it in the physical world, as a brick or tile.  Incidentally, the word 'corpse', comes from the same root.  A 'corpse' is a body that no longer has a 'spiritus' or 'mens'.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that "so to speak" is the writer's way of putting quotes around the word "corporeal" to suggest that this should not be read as a literal meaning of the term.

> and this allegedly confused, hazy Hegelian notion appears [figuratively speaking] in corporeal form in things and processes.

The writer could have simply said:

> and this allegedly confused, hazy Hegelian notion *takes shape* in things and processes.

A larger context for the passage might let us understand whether this is just poor writing or a witty remark of some kind.

Comment: I looked at paragraphs before and after the one quoted (which can be seen near the end of [a chapter](http://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1877/anti-duhring/ch10.htm) of ***Anti-Dühring*** by Frederick Engels) and concluded that it is not a witty remark of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

To my observation,  faith is the substance of things 
unseen,  and thus,  unknown in the natural state of 
physical places.  That in the essence of religion explains the creed of not trusting one's own understanding as the object of creation but rathet in a supernatural source of creation.   However,  in the 
context of places discerned or discivered in the human  consciousness,  is the  sensory perception of the corporeal; e. g.  structural, dimensions of things with energy,  space,  time and value to the
identificational relative affect of emotional interests 
to have and to produce in physical natural environments of human habitation.  Corporeal form is a synonymical term to describe a concept of 
positive rightness of human acceptance of the
quality of balance and function and stability in the
quantoty or plural quantities of individual or
societal welfare: as in Psalms 23, yeaness though 
of goneness through in paths of righteousness of 
our own natural namesakes.